# Sending JSP form POST information to email

Tags: html, jsp

This is probably a simple question but I'm having difficulty finding the solution online. I have created a simple HTML form within a JSP ('Enter name' text box and a submit button). I'm trying to find out if there is a way to send the POST information to a set email address. I don't want the user to have to pick a email to send it to which I know can be done with servlets. Rather than having the Name display when I click the submit button, I want the name to be sent to a email address that has been set on the backend.  Could someone please link me to a tutorial where this can be done?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? select from existing emails stored on server?

Comment: No. Basically, I want all form information to be sent to an email address. Any name entered will be forwarded to a email address that has been set on the backend.

Comment: I found the solution. Aparrently, you can use mailto:your@email.address in the action attribute of your form. Although It seems that not all browsers properly support this.

Comment: are you seeking for client-side solution? I thought that you want to process it server side (jsp)

Comment: I guess it's more of a client-side solution. I just don't want the client to control what address the form results are sent to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how to send email: http://java2s.com/Code/Java/Email/Createaverysimpletextplainmessageandsendsit.htm. Text message shall contain values of form parameters - request.getParameter()

Comment: I think using this example I would have to provide the email address in the form?  Using this                                          <form action=mailto:your@email.address method="POST" 
 enctype="text/plain"> the client will have all POST data emailed without having to provide one.  I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it looks like the easiest.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I could have my form reference a java program on the server side that will send the email. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can store recepient email address either in some property file stored in classpath or as servlet parameter in web.xml along with other JavaMail properties (hostname, authorization).